# Flutter: url launcher facebook and instagram showing it may be broken

Tags: flutter

```
 await launchUrl(
                  Uri.parse(
                    'https://www.facebook.com/$fbid',
                  ),
                  mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
```

I have this launch url mode. The address works when I use it on my browser however, it does not when I use it inside the Flutter app. It says `The link you followed may be broken, or ....`

Twitter works fine but `Instagram` and `FB` are the ones that cause the error. I feel like something must be done for meta apps that I am missing right now. How can I fix this?

Answer (score -1):

### if (Platform.isAndroid) { var fbUrl = "fb://facewebmodal/f?href=" + "https://www.facebook.com/$fbid "; //for android launchFacebook(fbUrl, "https://www.facebook.com/$fbid"); }